# BI Publisher Report Runs slow but running in SQL Developer is fast

Tags: oracle, bi-publisher

We have a BI Publisher report that calls a function. When running the function in SQL Developer with
select * from table (function(parameters)) it is completing within 7 minutes. We have the same query in BI Publisher and its running 2 hrs which is a lot.

For more context.

- Data came from an older version of the application we are upgrading, so the data is imported and upgraded to the new version of the schema.
- database is a controlled enviroment we only got a READ Only user in SQL Developer
- BI Publisher data source user (i dont have the password for this so cannot test) is the schema owner where the function resides ( I tried creating a datasource with the Read only user used in SQL Developer but still the same 2 hr run time)

What things can I check to identify the issue ?

I am trying to track down every SQL used in the function for the execution plan. to try and capture it from the old version and apply it to the new one.

Thanks in advance!

I tried to use the user that we are using in SQL Developer as the data source of the report but still the same run time, I am expecting that it would be the same but its not.

Comment: Ask your DBA to capture the actual SQL that the database is executing. BI might be adding something or changing it in some way.

Comment: I can see that in session BI is actually executing the same sql that I did. However I did not see if it added hints or whatever. We will retest and the DBA will monitor. I did find some of the SQL in the function has high buffergets/execution

Comment: @AnthonyNieveraJr When you ran on SQL Developer, did the IDE retrieve all of the rows or only the first 50 rows? Also, check that the code does not have any implicit date format conversions; there's a good chance that SQL Developer and BI Publisher use different session level date format settings, which can occasionally cause bugs or performance differences when implicit date formats are used.

Comment: @AnthonyNieveraJr, if you could not see whether it added hints, then you cannot see that it is the same SQL. A hint makes it a different SQL. Verify that the sql_id for both are the same, and if not, there's something different about them. Also check session parameters and fetching limits as Jon says. To test fetching limits wrap the whole thing in a `select count(*) from <original query>)` and time it in SQL Developer.

Comment: 7 minutes to run SQL seems like a long time to me. Something gathering data for BI Publisher should not take that long. Let alone 2 hours.